# XUL buttons and textboxes resist styling

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

Given

```
<button label="Login" class="ATKButton" />
```

Only some of the styles in my CSS definition are being applied. The style rules appear in the DOM inspector, but some seem to be ignored.

Here is the style definition, with comments on what types of rules work and which are ignored.

```
.ATKButton{
    background: linear-gradient(#333333, #222222); #ignored
    border: 1px solid #111111; #ignored
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px; #ignored
    text-transform: uppercase; #ignored
    font-weight: bold; #ignored        
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; #ignored
    text-align:right; #ignored

    color: white; #obeyed
    cursor: pointer; #obeyed        
    font-size: 10px; #obeyed
    height: 28px; #obeyed
    width: 120px; #obeyed
}
```

I also tried directly applying the stubborn styles, like:

```
<button label="Login" class="ATKButton" style="background: linear-gradient(#333333, #222222);" />
```

To no effect. Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) will (usually) override such changes. Set it to `none` to disable platform-specific appearance and use your styles instead.